# How to use jsoncpp without jsoncpp.dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, jsoncpp

```
strcpy(this->encoding, jsonvalue.get("encoding", "").asCString());
```

I need to work with json data in my program, yesterday i downloaded it using nuGet, coded all i needed, commented path to `jsoncpp.lib` but system doesnt allow me to start the program due to missing `jsoncpp.dll`. Does this mean i need to take the dll everywhere with my program? If so, im not happy with that so can i solve this? Or if its impossible, which json libraries that doesnt require dll can i use ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to compile *jsoncpp* as a *static* library. I don't know if the license permit that (i.e. redistributions of binaries linked to a static library), and I don't know how to do that on Windows. I would believe you should distribute the `.dll` with your program. Read about [DLL hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)

Comment: That's the problem: i dont want people to take the dll everywhere with my program when i share it. I hate when people do that and dont want to do myself. Its just small program 2000 rows of code, not big project with installer and thousands features.

Comment: You could make your program free software and publish your source code. The burden of compiling JSONCPP is then left to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [download amalgamation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/files/jsoncpp/0.6.0-rc2/) (all source is in one file)
- add `jsoncpp.cpp` to your project
- uncomment `#define JSON_IS_AMALGAMATION` in `json.h`
- add `#include "json/json.h"` at the beginning of your source code

Comment: if your compiler can't find `json/json.h` be sure to add its _parent folder_ to your include paths

Comment: You don't need to uncomment `#define JSON_IS_AMALGAMATION`. The amalgamated header sets that up for you. You need only to set your include path properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the *latest* source-code. The project has moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/). `cmake` would probably solve your problem.